# Equivalent of Partition Magic for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

which is the equivalent of Partition Magic for Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you intend to do? Be more specific. In general, to modify partitions you can use GParted.

Answer (score 5):

Gparted is what you're looking for.  If you need to resize the partition of your current OS you'll need to use a live cd like the one Gparted provides [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) or you can use something like [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org) which also has Gparted built in.

Good luck!

Comment: @Marco if you think, this is the answer, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the light gray tick mark. thanks :)